# Formato de data c#

Tags: c#

Preciso formatar a data para **Apr 06, 2018**.
Código que eu tenho:

```
DateTime joinDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Group.GetGroupJoinInfo(Group.Id));

base.WriteString(joinDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, crie um objeto `DateTime` com a data desejada:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact("06/04/2018", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Depois, converta para o formato desejado:

```
string resultDate = date1.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

#### Melhorando tratamento da data

É possível que a conversão gere exceção caso não esteja no formato correto. Para isso melhorei o código para o seguinte.

```
try
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact("06/04/2018", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date1))
    {
        throw new FormatException("Formato de data inválido");
    }

    string resultDate = date1.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Tratar exceção gerada, seja mostrando uma mensagem ou registrando em um arquivo de log
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, só foi necessário alterar dentro do "toString".

Comment: Se você vai gerar uma exceção de qualquer forma, não era mais simples ter colocado o try-catch logo no primeiro exemplo?

Comment: Sim, porém eu já tinha respondido daquela forma e achei melhor apenas adicionar uma melhoria no código.